# OSDK4.x: Can you use DJI Assistant 2 for Matrice with payload actions?

Tags: dji-sdk

**Is it possible with OSDK4.x to command payload and flight actions and use the DJI Assistant 2 for Matrice concurrently?**

Previously, we have been using the M210V1 with OSDK3.9. Using the DJI Assistant 2 for Matrice to simulate the drone flight is key to our ability to develop our system.

However, the M210V2 and OSDK4.x require the USB port of the drone to be connected to the Linux device running the OSDK, otherwise any payload (`GimbalManager`, `CameraManager`) actions throw an error - such as `GimbalManager::resetSync`.

This is not ideal for development since we cannot use the simulator (on MacOS) and connect the USB to the Linux device (there is only one USB port on the drone). Has anyone solved this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

For 210, There is only one USB2 port and it is either for connecting to PC side assitant2 or connecting to onboard PC to get osdk stream. You can think it as a bug in design phases.

Yes, you can run part of osdk and run the simulator without the payload camera-related function. If I recall correctly, I can still "rostopic echo" the Gimbal orientation topic from the drone. Its only image topic that is disabled.  You can simulate the GPS based flight in simulator and try to set gimbal direction. I remember this was achievable.

There is no way for you to run both simulators and get payload functions such as images from OSDK. so to get both image running and drone running in simulator that's not achievable.

If you really wants both at same time. I suggest you move to M300 which they have dual USB C interface for both camera stream and for simulation.

Comment: You can also use the `M210configtool` (located in `Onboard-SDK/utility/<sys-arch>/`) to initialize a non-graphical simulator: 
`$ ./M210ConfigTool --usb-port /dev/ttyACM0 --config-file UserConfig.txt --simulation on --latitude 37.422083 --longitude -122.137390`
This allows gimbal/camera/advanced sensing & flight action related functionality, at the cost of non-graphical simulation. See [this page](https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/M210-Docs/simulation-checklist.html) for more info.